# php function arguments var, reset argument

Tags: php, function, arguments, var

I created a php function and I want to clear/reset the arguments of the function.

for example I've got this function declared twice in my index.php:

```
grid_init($type='portfolio',$postNb=4,$rowNb=2);
grid_init($type='post',$postNb,$rowNb);

function grid_init($type,$postNb,$rowNb) {
?>

<div class="container" data-type="<?php echo $type; ?>" data-postNb="<?php echo $rowNb; ?>" data-rowNb="<?php echo $rowNb; ?>">
some stuff.....
</div>

<?php
}
```

If I didn't specified my argument in my second function (in the above example `$postNb $rowNb`), these vars will take the values of the previous argument declared in the previous function (`$postNb=4,$rowNb=2`)...

How can I reset/clear my argument in my function between each function declared in a same file?

Comment: You're going to want to make use of Classes.

Comment: What do you mean by classes? SOrry I'm not familiar with PHP... I know how to write a script or a classical function at the moment...

Comment: Show the declared function, not executed, please. There is no reason to use `$type='portfolio'`, instead of just `'portfolio'` in a function you are calling.

Comment: By the way, in my function I've got more than 20 arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a function have default arguments it's like:

```
function grid_init($type, $postNb = 2, $rowNb = 4){
  echo "<div class='container' data-type='$type' data-postNb='$rowNb' data-rowNb='$rowNb'>".
  "some stuff.....".
  '</div>';
}
```

Execute like:

```
grid_init('whatever'); // will assume $postNb = 2 and $rowNb = 4;
grid_init('some_data_type', 42, 11); // overwrite your defaults
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. So If I type `11` in third argument it will automatically know that it correspond to $rowNb in my example? And for empty argument does `grid_init(,,$rowNb = 4)` will work? It's not really easy to do it with a lots of argument in php...

Comment: Yes it would if you pass `11` as the third argument, and no leaving an argument out in the middle would pass `null` as the argument.

Comment: You may also consider `$args = func_get_args();` inside your function. Then you don't have to have any arguments in your defined function, and you can test for `if(isset($args[0])){/*stuff here*/}` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have trouble calling functions.

Change your calls to

```
grid_init('portfolio',4,2);
grid_init('post','',''); // or use '' as default
```

a) you might have declared a function like this

```
function grid_init($type, $postNb, $rowNb)
{
   // do stuff on $tyoe, $postNb, $rowNb
}
```

b) you might call the function several times, each time with new parameters

```
grid_init('post', 5, 4);
grid_init('somewhere', 1, 2);
```

A function does not memorize values of prior calls.
If you want that, then save them somewhere from within that function.

c) you might use default parameters on your function

Default parameters always come last in the function declaration.

```
function grid_init($type, $postNb = 2, $rowNb = 2)
{
    // do stuff on $tyoe, $postNb, $rowNb
}
```

call it

```
grid_init('somewhere');
```

now postNb, rowNb are not set, but the default values from the declaration are used.

d) keep the number of parameters low!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can't keep it lower it's a plugin with lots of options and options seems to don't affect my performance...

Comment: It's a rule of thumb - but you might implement it, the way you like it.